# Javascript Regex expression for matching words with digits ignoring 4 digit numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that is just words with a single whitespace in-between. Assuming no special characters I would like to match all words containing digits while ignoring 4 digit numbers.

I.E.

`hello12345 12345hello 123456789 12 red hello 1234 5678`

Would Match:

`hello12345 12345hello 123456789 12`

The ultimate goal would be replacing `hello12345 12345hello 123456789 12` with an empty string resulting in:

`red hello 1234 5678`

The following `\w*\d\w*` matches words with digits
and `\b\d{4}\b` matches all 4 digit numbers.
However, I am unsure of how to combine them.

Comment: .`\d{1,3}\b`?..

Comment: Capture what you need and just match what you do not  need - [`/\b\d{4}\b|(\w*\d\w*)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/lGQteD/1/codegen?language=javascript) and collect Group 1 (if you need to extract).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am still quite new to regex could you explain what you mean?

Comment: @YAnderson So, is that clear now?

Answer (score 1):

Match and *capture* what you need and just match what you do not need (see [*The Best Regex Trick Ever*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick)):

```js
var re = /\b\d{4}\b|(\w*\d\w*)/g;
var str = "hello12345 12345hello 123456789 12 red hello 1234 5678";
var m, res = [];
while (m = re.exec(str)) {
    if (m[1]) res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

The `\b\d{4}\b` alternative is only matched, but the second one, `(\w*\d\w*)`, is also *captured* with the help of the capturing group, `(...)`. This value is kept in Group 1, accessed via `m[1]`.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for that, after having another look I understand!

Comment: @YAnderson If it works for you please consider accepting. If you found it helpful please consider upvoting. If you need any help with this solution please drop a comment and I will be happy to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

This regex

```
/((\b(\d{1,3}|\d{5,})\b)|([a-z]+\d\w*|\w*\d[a-z]+))\s*/gi
```

matches:

```
// Digit-only words with less than or more than 4 digits
\b(\d{1,3}|\d{5,})\b

// Words that contain at least a number and a letter
[a-z]+\d\w*|\w*\d[a-z]+
```

incl. whitespace between them.

```js
var string = "hello12345 12345hello 123456789 12 red hello 1234 5678";
var regex = /((\b(\d{1,3}|\d{5,})\b)|([a-z]+\d\w*|\w*\d[a-z]+))\s*/gi
console.log(string.replace(regex, ""));
```

There might be a simpler one. That's just from the top of my head.